# Uncaught TypeError when creating a dropdown button in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create Dropdown button using Bootstrap 5, but I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: t.createPopper is not a function

This is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown link
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

These are the scripts I am using:

```html
<script src="assets/scripts/vendors/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/vendors/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/vendors/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is working but probably the Bootstrap or the Popper Library is not complete, try using CDN instead of the offline library.

[The official documentation of Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/).

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <!--official Bootstrap CDN-->
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="dropdown">
         <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
         Dropdown link
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: offline version prevents hacking via middleman. it is the right approach.

Comment: @RickyLevi First: I do not think you can get hacked from using CDN. Second: Personally I prefer CDN as they faster than Offline Library. Offline Libraries needs fast hosting to your site work fast otherwise it will be slow.

Comment: the world has changed, read in owasp.org. almost every hi-tech company strongly suggest never to use a cdn link ( only for testing/1minute coding examples, but never for production ) it is not safe. link: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Third_Party_Javascript_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html. maybe bootstrap is something that you *might* trust. but even with `integrity` their code might change to collect information or something that you don't want. i'm just writing it down - for other people to know and consider. not specifically for your answer - this is why i didn't downgrade it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` or `bootstrap.bundle.js` as an offline library which contains Popper.
Ex:-

```
<script src="src/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

This solved my problem. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can confirm using bundle instead of importing popper.js and bootstrap.js separately fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the popper version. I don't know what they did but with the recent version of popper the dropdown does not work anymore.

I used version 1.14.3 to make it work in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e5n1astx/

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code I used above.
Link to popper version I used: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to import the popper js into your code. Follow the link: https://popper.js.org/
After that it will work normally

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
```

Comment: Consider editing your answer to describe how this answers resolves the problem described in the question.

Comment: Please try as much as possible to answer the question as best as possible without including links to other sites. You can do this by explaining what was said on the external site.

Answer (score -3):

this saved me:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<!--Bootsrap 4 CDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--Fontawesome CDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   Dropdown button
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.